# Contraction of simplicial presheaves

Tags: simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Let $X,Y$ be two simplicial presheaves on a small category $\mathcal{C}$, let $*$ be the final simplicial presheaf. Consider the category of simplicial presheaves equipped with its projective model structure.I want to prove or disprove the following thing:

Assume that there exists two weak equivalences $X\to *$, $Y\to *$, then there exists a weak equivalence $f\: : \: X\to Y$. Moreover any two such weak equivalences are homotopic.

Comment: Taking $X = *$, this implies that $Y$ has a global section; this seems unlikely.

Comment: Well, if you assume $X$ is cofibrant and $Y$ is fibrant then you do get such a weak equivalence.